# Bounding Box restrictions in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, bounding-box

I have a collection in mongodb that contains records in the following form:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("60608df8f2119229109345e8"), 
    "geometry" : {
       "type" : "Point", 
       "coordinates" : [ 23.589316, 37.952651 ] 
    }, 
    "type" : "Feature", 
    "properties" : {
        "accID" : "100000299", 
        "timestamp" : "2020-03-01T21:59:04Z" 
    }
}
```

I want to create an another collection which contains only the records rely inside a bounding box. The bounding box is defined by some coordinates. More specific the query in PostgreSQL is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE RecordsFiltered AS
SELECT DISTINCT ON(accID,time) *
FROM OriginalTable
WHERE Longitude BETWEEN 23.0301 and 24.3567 AND Latitude BETWEEN 37.2781 AND 38.4802;
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to perform a geospatial query to find documents based on a longitude and latitude?

Comment: No, I wanto create a new collection that will contains only records indise a bounding box. The BB is defined by the coordinates shown in the PostgreSQL query.

Comment: Looking at the SQL script and the name filtered, I would assume that this is a changing table that records will be added overtime (maybe I am wrong in this one) and create a view instead of a table so that the new records will always be available, that's why I was asking about the query but you want to create documents and insert them into another collection based on the bounding box (longitude and latitude combination)?

Comment: Please have a look at the $box doc https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/box/